# Regex does not find phone number inside text

Tags: regex

I want to find phone number inside text using regex. My forula for phone number is:

```
(?:(?:\+?\d*\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{3})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
```

The numer is being found when it is in one line without any other text. But when it is in the middle of some text it is not being found. How can I fix that?

Here is the link with the example:
[regexr.com/3rf0l](http://regexr.com/3rf0l)

Comment: Not a bad start, but there are some limitations. If the +1 is in fact a country code, 10 digit phone numbers are dropping off the 10th digit. Additionally, though removing the $ as suggested below will answer your question, you'll need to play with situations where lines end in numbers and begin with numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your regex ends by `$`, which is an anchor for the end of the line/document (depending on your multiline settings).

For example, in the string `1a2b`, the regex `[a-z]$` will match `b` but not `a`, because it's not at the end of the string, while `[a-z]` will match both.

Remove it and it will work:

```
(?:(?:\+?\d*\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{3})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/769LLb/1)